# How do I stop Visual Studio from Inserting Namespaces into the Designer Code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is driving me to distraction and I can't stop it from happening.

I have a class called MultiColumnCombo and use it as a tool I drag onto forms. The problem I have is the Designer code is being changed to include the NameSpace 'ACUITY_DATA', generating an error ('ACUITY_DATA' is the name of the project). When I delete ACUITY_DATA, it works fine. But every time I adjust something on the form, Visual Studio reinserts ACUITY_DATA again, breaking the application:

MyControls.MultiColumnCombo() = Works Fine

ACUITY_DATA.MyControls.MultiColumnCombo() = error (visual studio keeps changing it back to this)

I have tried creating my own Name Space 'MyControls' in an attempt to fix it but it didn't work.

It's driving me crazy. Any ideas would be appreciated...

The error is receive is "ACUITY_DATA.MyControls.MultiColumnCombo() is not defined"

Although I have mentioned this above, I use the class object by dragging it from the Components area of the Toolbox onto a form. It is this that is causing the problems.

The class looks like this:

```
Namespace MyControls
    Public Class MultiColumnCombo
        Inherits ComboBox

                CODE...

    End Class    
End Namespace
```

This is in the designer:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class frmStaffAllocations
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(frmStaffAllocations))
      
        Me.mcboPts = New ACUITY_DATA.MyControls.MultiColumnCombo()
        Me.cboEnterUser = New ACUITY_DATA.MyControls.MultiColumnCombo()
        Me.lblPC_Name = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblPC_User = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        
        lots of other code...
        
End Class
```

Comment: What is `MyControls` in "MyControls.MultiColumnCombo() = Works Fine"? Please tell me that you haven't defined that class inside another class.

Comment: What is the root namespace for your project and is that `MultiColumnCombo` class declaration inside anything else, e.g. a namespace and/or a class or module?

Comment: No, I have not defined a class within a class. Someone suggested using the keyword Namespace as a wrapper around the class to see if it would stop these crazy shenanigans, but it didn't work.

The root NameSpace is "ACUITY.DATA", but no other object in the projects uses it in the designer.

I have edited the original post with some code to hope better explain

Comment: Tbh, the NameSpace 'Mycontrols' really doesn't do anything extra and the code behaves the same without it. I placed it here to show what I have tried. SO really the NameSpace MyControls could be ignored.

Comment: When you add a control/component in the designer, the generated uses the fully-qualified name of the type, e.g. `System.Windows.Forms.Label` that you can see in the code you posted. When you create a project, the root namespace for that project is the same as the project name by default. If you named your project "ACUITY_DATA" then that is the default root namespace that all types in your project are members of. If you add another namespace, e.g. `MyControls`, it is a child of that root. A type `X` declared in that child namespace is thus `ACUITY_DATA.MyControls.X`.  What error is generated?

Comment: What you describe is exactly what should be happening, other than the error, which you haven't actually described. For future reference, we should never have to ask you to provide an error message.

Comment: For the record, I just tested what you describe under both .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 6 and had no issues. I named my project "ACUITY_DATA" and copied your `MultiColumnCombo` class in. Whether or not I included the `MyControls` namespace, it worked every time. As it always does, the designer code included the fully-qualified name, e.g. `Me.MultiColumnCombo1 = New ACUITY_DATA.MultiColumnCombo()`. I can only conclude that either something is corrupt in your project or on your system or you're doing something else that you're not telling us about. I'd try a new project as a test.

Comment: The error I get is "ACUITY_DATA.MyControls.MultiColumnCombo() is not defined". In your testing, did you drag the class object from the components area of the tools menu onto a form?

Comment: I'm wondering whether that error message indicates that that specific constructor doesn't exist. If you want to be able to add a control or component in the designer then it has to have a parameterless constructor. Have you added any constructors to your class and, if so, does one of them have no parameters? If the answers are "yes" and "no" then that is the issue. BTW, yes I did drag my control from the Toolbox to the form.

Comment: Yes, I have only one constructor and it IS parameterless. I'm really at a loss. I don't understand why Visual studio is persistently reinserting the prefix namespace 'ACUTIY_DATA'. I have even tried to construct this as a windows form control and then reference it from the ACUITY_DATA app, but i can't get this to work either

Comment: *"I don't understand..."*. yes you do because I've told you: the WinForms designer ALWAYS uses the fully-qualified name of the type in that context and the root namespace for your project IS the name of the project, unless you changed it. What is complicated about that? Like I said, exactly what you described worked for me so I would suggest that you create a new test project and test exactly that and only that. If it works in the new project then there's something amiss in your old project. If the new project doesn't work either then VS may be broken and need a repair.

Comment: Ok, but i do Not understand why this is happening with this project. I have no idea what could be causing this. Even if it worked in a brand new project, moving my entire project into a new build is not feasible; it's too big!

Comment: It's actually not unfeasible but, regardless, how about you just do it so we can at least identify what problem you need to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea why the issue occurred, however, I moved my project from VS 2017 to VS 2022 and it fixed it. Go figure!